# Python Pandas DtypeWarning Specify dtype option on import - How?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have these columns:

```
['Campaign', 'Ad group', 'Keyword', 'Status', 'Match type', 'Max. CPC', 'Quality score', 'Impressions', 'Clicks', 'CTR', 'Avg. CPC', 'Cost', 'Avg. position', 'Converted clicks', 'Click conversion rate', 'Cost / converted click', 'Bounce rate', 'Pages / session', 'Avg. session duration (seconds)', '% new sessions']
```

The error I'm receiving says:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1164
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
DtypeWarning: Columns (5) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
```

What does the `Columns (5)` part mean?  Is  that the column position?  Does `Campaign` column start at position 0 or 1?

Also, I suspect this error is because my `Max. CPC` column has `' --'` in a few areas instead of zeros.  I want this column datatype to be a float.  How do I translate these `' --'` to `0.00` and also set this column as a float datatype when reading the CSV?

I've tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', dtype={'Max. CPC': pd.np.float64})

print(df.head())
```

But get a ValueError:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ' --'
```

Comment: You could pass `na_values=[' --']` this will convert these values to `naN` and the dtype will then float, or replace these values after loading to 0.00 and then the dtype of the column would be float, as for your columns error you'll need to post the raw input in order for us to reproduce your error

Comment: @EdChum Thank you.  I didn't know about na_values.  There are so many parameters in read_csv.  Thanks for helping me along my learning quest. In case anyone is interested, this is my final line for clarity:
`df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', na_values=[' --'], dtype={'Max. CPC': pd.np.float64})`

Comment: the only thing here is that `NaN` is not what you wanted, but you could call `fillna` after reading the csv to set the values to 0.00, this assumes you want all `NaN` to be set to 0.00, including possibly any `NaN` values that were originally present in the csv

Comment: OK, I think I get it now.  After creating `df`, I need to set the `NaN` to `0.00` using `fillna` like this?  `df['Max. CPC'] = df['Max. CPC'].fillna(0.00)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 approaches I can think of, one is to pass a list of values that [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) can consider to treat as `NaN` values, this would convert those values in the list to be converted to `NaN` so that the dtype of that column remains as a `float` and not `object`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', dtype={'Max. CPC': pd.np.float64}, na_values=[' --'])
```

You can then convert these `NaN` values to `0.00` calling [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html#pandas.Series.fillna):

```
df['Max. CPC'] = df['Max. CPC'].fillna(0.00)
```

The other is to load as before and [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html#pandas.Series.replace) these values to `0.00`:

```
df['Max. CPC'] = df['Max. CPC'].replace(' --', 0.00)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the solution. What does the "Column(5)" mean? Column index 5 starting with 0?

Comment: Yes, starting with zero. My error says (3) but it was the fourth column that had mixed string and numbers