# in Pandas, when using read_csv(), how to assign a NaN to a value that's not the dtype intended?

Tags: python, pandas

**Note:** Please excuse my very low skilled English, feel free to modify the question's title, or the following text to be more understandable

I have this line in my code:

```
moto = pd.read_csv('reporte.csv')
```

It sends a **`DtypeWarning: Columns (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13) have mixed types.`** warning, so I change it to

```
moto = pd.read_csv('reporte.csv', dtype={'TP': np.float64})
```

Now it drops a **`ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'None'`**.

I checked the file (around 200K lines) with Excel, and yes, I found some cells with "**None**" value.

So my question is: **Is there a way to ignore the error, or force python to fill the offending error with NaN or something else?**

I tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30314153/python-pandas-dtypewarning-specify-dtype-option-on-import-how) but it didn't work.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I tried creating a csv to replicate this feedback but couldn't on pandas 0.18, so I can only recommend two methods to handle this:

**First**

If you know that your missing values are all marked by a string 'none', then do this:

```
moto = pd.read_csv("test.csv", na_values=['none'])
```

You can also add, to the na_values list, other markers that should be converted to NaNs.

**Second**

Try your first line again without using the dtype option.

```
moto = pd.read_csv('reporte.csv')
```

The read is successful because you are only getting a warning. Now execute `moto.dtypes` to show you which columns are objects. For the ones you want to change do the following:

```
moto.test_column = pd.to_numeric(moto.test_column, errors='coerce')
```

The 'coerce' option will convert any problematic entries, like 'none', to NaNs.

To convert the entire dataframe at once, you can use convert_objects. You could also use it on a single column, but that usage is deprecated in favor of to_numeric. The option, convert_numeric, does the coercion to NaNs:

```
moto = moto.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

After any of these methods, proceed with [fillna](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to do what you need to.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. In the end I used the `errors='coerce'`. I also was able to use the `na_values`, I think I missunderstood the documentation the first time

Comment: this is great for a single column, but what if you have very many columns? You'd have to run this `to_` over and over again right?

Answer (score 1):

A great answer, [wordsmith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/996514/wordsmith) ! Just to add a couple of minor things:

- there is a typo in the answer, data.test_column should probably be moto.test_column
- convert_objects is now deprecated, in favor of type-specific methods on columns, one-at-a-time [why?]

A full working example, including the dropping of the lines containing read errors (not column count errors, covered by read_csv(..., error_bad_lines=False) would be:

```
moto = pd.read_csv('reporte.csv')
moto.test_column = pd.to_numeric(moto.test_column, errors='coerce')
moto.dropna(axis='index',how='any',inplace=True)
```

I would also like to offer an alternative:

```
from pandas import read_csv
import numpy as np

# if the data is not a valid "number", return a NaN
# note that it must be a float, as NaN is a float:  print(type(np.nan))
def valid_float(y):
  try:
    return float(y)
  except ValueError:
    return np.nan

# assuming the first row of the file contains the column names 'A','B','C'...
data = read_csv('test.csv',header=0,usecols=['A','B','D'],
   converters={'A': valid_float, 'B': valid_float, 'D': valid_float} )

# delete all rows ('index') with an invalid numerical entry
data.dropna(axis='index',how='any',inplace=True)
```

This is fairly compact and readable at the same time. For a true one-liner, it would be great to (1) re-write the validation function as lambda code, and (2) do the dropping of defective rows directly in the call to read_csv, but I could not figure out how to do either of these.

Answer (score 0):

According to the `Pandas` documentation, these values are interpreted as `NaN` by default, so changing entries from `None` to one of these may fix the problem.

By default the following values are interpreted as NaN:

```
‘’, ‘#N/A’, ‘#N/A N/A’, ‘#NA’, ‘-1.#IND’, ‘-1.#QNAN’, 
‘-NaN’, ‘-nan’, ‘1.#IND’, ‘1.#QNAN’, ‘<NA>’, ‘N/A’,
‘NA’, ‘NULL’, ‘NaN’, ‘n/a’, ‘nan’, ‘null’.
```

Source: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html