# reading borked CSV files with pd.read_csv (irregular delimiters, custom NA)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, unicode, separator

I'm reading CSV data to be used as a pandas dataframe, but the CSV does not appear to follow any sane convention (besides using `;` as delimiter, as everyone should...). It appears that the sole goal was to make them look *good* when opened in a text editor

Here's some examples (set up as variables, so that they can be used for the reader examples):

```
ex1="""
Type: Some Metadata
User: More Metadata
Data:
01.10.1939 00:00:00   ;   1,1 ;     
01.12.1939 00:00:00   ;   1   ;     
01.01.1940 00:00:00   ;  10   ;     
"""
```

OK, decimal comma (easy), semicolon delimiter (easy), dayfirst (easy) and a bunch of metadata (skiprows, also easy).

```
ts = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(ex1), skiprows=4, decimal=',', sep=';',
                 index_col=0, usecols=[0,1], dayfirst=True,
                 parse_dates=True, names=['date', 'val'])
```

`print(ts` results in a nice dataframe

```
             val
date
1939-10-01   1.1
1939-12-01   1.0
1940-01-01  10.0
```

and `ts.index` is a nice `DatetimeIndex` and `type(ts.val[0])` is a `numpy.float64`, as it should be. But let's introduce a *creative* way to mark `NaN`:

```
ex2="""
Type: Some Metadata
User: More Metadata
Data:
01.10.1939 00:00:00   ;   1,1;        
01.12.1939 00:00:00   ; NÄ  ;       
01.01.1940 00:00:00   ;  10   ;   
"""
```

The above `ts=read_csv...` still works without error, but `NÄ` breaks the `val` column and turns it to strings. But when I change this to

```
ts = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(ex2), skiprows=4, decimal=',', sep=';',
                 index_col=0, usecols=[0,1], dayfirst=True,
                 parse_dates=True, names=['date', 'val'],
                 na_values='NÄ')
```

using [`na_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html?highlight=na_values), the whole thing fails. `print(ts)`

```
                val
date
1939-10-01      1,1
1939-12-01     NÄ
1940-01-01    10
```

Not only did it not accept `NÄ` as `NaN`, this also turns all `val`s into strings, thus ignores the decimal comma and keeps the trailing spaces. `ts.val[0]` is now `'   1,1'`, so a simple `ts.val = ts.val.astype(float)` of course fails.

**What am I doing wrong with `na_values='NÄ'`?**

**Why does it also break `decimal','` and adds the spaces?**

It seems like `skipinitialspace=True` should help, but of course `NÄ` still breaks the `val` column.
`sep='\s*[;]s*'` seems promising, and

```
ts = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(ex2), skiprows=4, decimal=',' ,sep='\s*[;]s*',
                 index_col=0, usecols=[0,1], dayfirst=True,
                 parse_dates=True, names=['date', 'val'],
                 na_values='NÄ')
```

gives an apparently nice `print(ts)`

```
               val
date
1939-10-01     1.1
1939-12-01      NÄ
1940-01-01      10
```

(note the decimal point!), but now I've got the weird situation that it did replace the comma, but `ts.val[0]` now is a string again, and still has the trailing spaces (`'   1.1'`).

**So how do I read in those borked files?**

The workaround I'm currently using is to read in the CSV with pure python (I have to read in the header (40 lines in the real files) anyways) and write it out into a proper CSV, to be read with pandas:

```
file = open(myfile, 'r', encoding='UTF-8')
table = file.readlines()
file.close()

for v1 in range(0, len(table)):
    table[v1] = table[v1].replace("NÄ", "NaN")
    table[v1] = table[v1].replace(",", ".")

dataoutput = ["date;val\r\n"]
for v1 in range(3, len(table)):
    dataoutput.append(table[v1])
f2 = open(myfile.replace('.csv', 'good.csv'), 'w')
for v1 in range(0, len(dataoutput)):
    f2.write(dataoutput[v1])
f2.close()

ts = pd.read_csv(myfile.replace('.csv', 'good.csv'), 
                 sep=';', usecols=[0, 1], index_col=0,
                 dayfirst=True, parse_dates=True)

ts.val = ts.val.astype(float)
```

But with a few thousand CSV files, reaching up to a megabyte in size, this isn't really an optimal solution, so I'd like to solve the `NÄ` issue in the import.

Comment: I might have missed something, but could specifying the dtypes in the call to `read_csv()`, do the trick, or maybe converting the values after the file is parsed?

Comment: You can specify values as a list: na_values=[ '-1.#IND ', ' 1.#INF ' ]; Also check for trailing spaces (check my example).

Comment: `dtype={'val':np.float64}` just errors with `ValueError: Unable to convert column val to type <class 'numpy.float64'>` and setting the `NÄ` in a list (`na_values=['NÄ']`) also doesn't change the outcome. Trailing (or leading) spaces could be an issue. Gotta see what a regex does.

Comment: Setting `NÄ` into spaces (`na_values='\s*[NÄ]\s*'`) appears to change nothing.

Comment: Other ideas: check the encoding. I have similar problems with German files. Here is my complete reading line: `df = pd.read_csv( join( path, filename ), sep=';', encoding='iso-8859-1', engine='c', skiprows=[0], usecols=colstouse, na_values=[ '-1.#IND ', ' 1.#INF ' ] )`

Comment: Last idea. If you can read and then convert (that is, converting after `.read_csv()`), then you can use `pd.to_numeric(data.test_column, errors='coerce')` like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40011736/776515

Comment: Good point on the encoding. That is another circle of hell that I left out in the example, but yes, that can also cause a lot of problems, especially if it's some rare or legacy encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sep` is mis-specified (it ends with `s*` instead of `\s*`, which means it's looking for between 0 and infinite `s` characters).  That's why you're only capturing the leading and not the trailing spaces after the `;`.  Incidentally, this was also interfering with (1), because you were trying to replace `'NÄ'` but the value was `'   NÄ'`.  Use `sep='\s*\;\s*'` instead.

One thing you can do in future is to print out the offending values by themselves to make sure they contain what they think you contain, e.g. `ts.iloc[1].val`.

Also, if the `NaN` value being in unicode is a problem, you can strip it before parsing:

```
csv = io.StringIO(ex2.replace(u'N\xc4', '[MISSING]'))
ts = pd.read_csv(csv, 
    skiprows=4, decimal=',', index_col=0, usecols=[0,1], 
    dayfirst=True, parse_dates=True, names=['date', 'val'], 
    na_values='[MISSING]', sep='\s*\;\s*')
```

...which would give...

```
             val
date
1939-10-01   1.1
1939-12-01   NaN
1940-01-01  10.0
```

Comment: How does `uex.replace` work when I'm not doing the example with `StringIO`, but instead `pd.read_csv('file.csv, skiprows=...`?

Comment: is there still something missing in `csv = open('file.csv').replace(u'N\xc4', '[MISSING]')`? Results in `AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'replace'` for me.

Comment: "Use `sep='\s*\;\s*'` instead" Damn, I could have sworn I always had the `\ ` before the `s`. Of course searching for the letter s doesn't make sense. Fixing the `sep` works, no `read().replace()` needed (which, btw doesn't preplace `NÄ` on my machine, I suppose file encodings wreaking havoc). Those CSV files are pure hell. Whoever wrote them hated everything that is not notepad.